# How to start other Servers Automatically after Django Server starts

Tags: python, django

I am using different Servers alongside Django Server. For Example MongoDB server and Celery[command]

I want to ask that how can I execute other CMD commands automatically whenever I start "**

> python manage.py runserver

**"

Comment: you can check for management command https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/08/27/how-to-create-custom-django-management-commands.html or https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a shell script which contains commands to start each service and then use it to get your projects running. For example here is a sample:

```
sudo service mongodb start
celery -A worker appname.celery
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what OS you use, on my Ubuntu for local development I do this:

Create .sh script. For example `start_project.sh` with this code:

```
cd /path/to/project
source /venv/bin/activate
python manage.py runserver & celery -A project worker --loglevel=debug
```

And then just run `bash start_project.sh`
Also you can add more commands to start separated by &

Answer (score 0):

Due to you use the term CMD I guess you use a Windows based OS. I would then say that you probably have the mongoDB service installation? (otherwise reinstall mongoDB as Service).

By defualt set to autostart (changable to non-autostart). If you changed the service for mongoDB to manual starting method, then you could start it in CMD as

```
net start mongoDB
```

I do not use/know what "Celery" is but quick google made it sound as some sort of message que. Which in my opinion should be or at least should have a service installation in which case you should use that and then use autostart/manual as described for mongoDB.